# How to create OpenMP threads only once (and do not kill them between different parallel regions)

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

I have an array `A_p` which is defined as `threadprivate` for each thread. The code is complicated and does some calculations. Finally, I want to reduce all the arrays to one `shared array A`.

```
DO J=1,Y
 DO I=1,X
   a=0
   !$omp parallel reduction(+:a)
      a = A_p(I,J)  
   !$omp end parallel
   A(I,J) = A(I,J)+ a
 END DO 
END DO
```

This solution works, but the problem is that the threads are probably created every iteration, which incurs a huge overhead. I would like to find a way to save the threads alive between the iterations, so they could be just created once.

I have also tried the following solution:

```
!$omp parallel reduction(+:A)
   A = A_p
!$omp end parallel
```

but it seems to create a certain overhead for initializing a `private` variable `A` for each thread (which by the way is redundant, because there are already `threadprivate` variables and we do not really need more private arrays). Of course the overhead here is smaller than the overhead observed in the previous solution, but still not good enough for me.

Also, I would like to ask about the way OpenMP implement the reduction. For example, in the first solution I presented, does the reduction of variable `a` is serial, or it is implemented in a tree combining fashion (achieving a logarithmic running time for the reduction phase)?

Comment: To answer the question in the title you can't except by only having one parallel region - it is totally up to the implementation what it does with threads between parallel regions. But what you want show above is quite strange, and it would really help if you could provide a minimal example code which shows what you want to do. I strongly suspect that the way you are trying to solve your problem is not the best way within OpenMP

Comment: *I would like to ask about the way OpenMP implement the reduction*  That's going to be implementation-dependent, the OpenMP standard is an API specification, not an implementation specification.  Personally, I'd be very surprised to learn that an implementation bothered with a tree-combining implementation of reduction; for the likely number of threads in OpenMP programs (100s at most, more often 10s or fewer) the theoretical benefits of the logarithmic complexity are probably just that, theoretical.

Comment: Default setting of OMP_WAIT_POLICY or equivalent in your openmp implementation should allow the thread pool to persist as the parallel region is exited and re-entered. This is not nearly as much overhead as constructing the thread pool from scratch. As mentioned above, your example doesn't make sense, doesn't explain why you don't make the outer loop omp parallel and the inner loop omp simd (omp simed reduction if appropriate).

Comment: As others say, threads will typically continue to exist even between parallel regions. The other threads will be idle. Some synchronization will happen at the start of a parallel region. This is completely implementation dependent and different compilers will have different OpenMP runtime libraries (libgomp, libiomp5,...) with different details.

Comment: If you want to speedup some code, you will have to show us the complete code that we can test ([mcve]) and all the relevant details (your compiler command, number of threads,...) and also your current performance measurements. Please take also the [tour] around this site.

Comment: "*the problem is that the threads are probably created every iteration, which incurs a huge overhead*" If your implementation does something stupid and inefficient that it could easily avoid doing, you should switch to a better implementation. Do you have any reason to think your implementation is that dumb? Surely it was made by people who understand this very obvious optimization?

Comment: I f you are on linux, strace your code and look at clone calls. That way you can convince yourself that OpenMP runtime implementors are not as stupid as you seem to think, and that they already use a thread pool. (As the OpenMP standard almost requires [look at the sections on the persistence of thread local variables...])

Comment: Why do you use `a = A_p(I,J)` and not `a += A_p(I,J)`? Did you check the results? Moreover, note that you can create an OpenMP section with `!$omp parallel` without performing directly a reduction.